# How to get Twitter organic impressions data from Twitter analytics API

Tags: json, api, twitter

I want to ask how could get Twitter **organic impressions** data from Twitter analytics **API** for a day? Is there any way via **JSON** or some other method. The idea is I could make a cron job and fetch all these data. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

There is no API endpoint for impressions data, outside the commercial API from https://gnip.com/ (Twitter property).

Alternatively, you could try https://github.com/philippe2803/twitter-analytics-wrapper in Python (I'm the author).

Comment: Can I get impression from this?

Comment: Is there no way to get impression of tweet from Python API?

Comment: Absolutely no way to get it for sure.

Comment: Thanks ,so sad !!

Comment: same for spend also? Don't we have API for spend and reach also?